# Swift - UIIMageView(Aspect Fill) and automatic row height

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, uiimageview, constraints

I'm trying to figure out how can I solve a problem.

Basically I have a Dynamic TableView, with dynamic Images(Different Sizes).

I want to set always a fixed width:320 for the UIImage and use the Mode: Aspect Fill(Without Clip Subviews), the image maintains the width and set the height dynamically based on my width, but the problem is, my image cover up everything else, like labels, buttons and edges of my cells, I tried to use auto-layout with constraints to reposition these other components(labels,buttons,etc), but not worked.

I don't know if just using the Interface Builder I can solve this behavior or I need to check/calculate some information programmatically.

Any ideas are welcome.
Thanks Team!

Answer (score 0):

Due to lacking of your code as example, I can just suggest you use a swift library from GitHub called [Toucan](https://github.com/gavinbunney/Toucan). Toucan is a Swift library that provides a clean, quick API for processing images. And it solve my image problem smoothly.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan Joe, but this is not exactly what I need, basically I don't have problems processing my images, but I have problems positioning the same with another elements like custom cells, labels, button.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this in Interface Builder.
I usually am always able to accomplish my desired layout using constraints and priorities. Only in cases with dynamic type it gets difficult.

I don't know the layout of your cell. It would be helpful if you would post a screenshot of your cell and indicate where the overlap occurs.